# Javascript to "copy in real time" some fields from a form to another form (with different input names)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to write a function to copy some fields (in real time) from a specific form, to another form

I try to be more specific:
I have 2 forms
- The first form is the one the user will fill in.
- The other form is hidden.
When the user will fill the first form, the second form (hidden) will be filled by the same informations.

Some fields are automatically filled by some calculations, so I can't use keyup/keypress or "click" to start the function

I wrote something like this, but it doesn't work

```
$(function(){
    var form1 = $('#form1'), 
    form2 = $('#form2');  
    $('#fieldname_form1').change(function(){
        $('input[name="inputname2"]', form2).val(function(){
            return $('input[name="inputname1"]', form1).val();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: May I ask you why the hidden form?

Comment: In what way does that not work? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown 
I have "no control" on the first form, because it is generated by a plugin
This first form is used just to calculate some values (prices)

So I have to add a second form.

After the user has made his calculations of his best price, he will fill the second form with his name and his email and he will send it to me.

So I have to "grab" values from the first form, I will put it in the second form (I hide the "cloned" fields by css, just to save space in the UI), in this way I can receive all the infos I need (calculations made by the user + name and email of the user)

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
$(function() {
  var form1 = $('#form1'), 
      form2 = $('#form2');  
      $('#fieldname_form1').change(function() {
          $('input[name="inputname2"]', form2).val($(this).val());
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me...

```js
$(function() {
  $('#i1').change(function(evt) {
    $('#i2').val(evt.target.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="i1" />
</form>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name2" id="i2" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy in real time using the `keyup function`, something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/piterio/9ytm8rm5/). Otherwise, when you say

> Some fields are automatically filled by some calculations

What do you mean? These calculations are made by you using JS or what? Because, if you are using JS you can fill the two fields at the same time when you make the calculations.

Comment: I have "no control" on the first form, because it is generated by a plugin
This first form is used just to calculate some values (prices)

So I have to add a second form.

After the user has made his calculations of his best price, he will fill the second form with his name and his email and he will send it to me.

So I have to "grab" values from the first form, I will put it in the second form (I hide the "cloned" fields by css, just to save space in the UI), in this way I can receive all the infos I need (calculations made by the user + name and email of the user)

Comment: Why you don't try to give us more information writing an example with JSFiddle? Maybe we can give you a better answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event is fired after the element has lost the focus. For the "user editable" elements you should use `keyup` (for the textbox) and `change` for the drop down elements.

On the other hand, for the fields filled automatically, you don't have any nice and clean solutions. I can think in two options:

1. If the calculations trigger is always the user changing some value, you could copy every form value after that happens.
2. (very bad option, but it would still work) You could be constantly checking for changes in every element and copying them using `setInterval` function.

*As a side note*

As well as your code should work, there is a simpler way to do it:

```
$('#fieldname_form1').change(function(){
    var value = $('input[name="inputname1"]', form1).val();
    $('input[name="inputname2"]', form2).val(value);
});
```